# Linux HA / cluster: what are the differences between Pacemaker, Heartbeat, Corosync, wackamole?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, high-availability, reliability, heartbeat

Can you help me understand Linux HA?

- Pacemaker, Heartbeat, Corosync seem to be part of a whole HA stack, but how do they fit together?
- How does wackamole differ from Pacemaker/Heartbeat/Corosync? I've seen opinions that wackamole is better than Heartbeat because it's peer-based. Is that valid?
- The last release of wackamole was 2.5 years ago. Is it still being maintained or active?
- What would you recommend for HA setup for web/application/database servers?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what kind of app is using the HA setup, MySQL? A cluster filesystem?

I'd recommend whichever HA setup redhat use in their cluster tools.
They tend to know which package is best for the general case. Accord into [this](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/csgfs/browse/rh-cs-en/ch-overview.html) is heartbeat, however [Planet HA](http://www.planet-ha.org/) has [interesting articles](http://www.planet-ha.org/#MySQL+scale-out+with+replication+and+Pacemaker) depending on what kind of stack you are configuring.